# Need help configuring Quarto for Neovim

Tags: neovim, quarto

I am relatively new to vim/neovim, and I am trying to configure Quarto for Neovim (https://quarto.org/docs/tools/neovim.html) for which the plugin is available here:

- https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-nvim

And a kickstarter setup is available here:

- https://github.com/jmbuhr/quarto-nvim-kickstarter

I took the time to read the documentation and copied some example configuration from the kickstarter, but could not get it working. I have no errors, but none of the functionalities work (see the videos here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLabWm-zCaD1axcMGvf7wFxJz8FZmyHSJ7).

My configuration files are here:

- https://github.com/PMassicotte/nvim

Specifically:

1. https://github.com/PMassicotte/nvim/blob/main/lua/plugins/init.lua
2. https://github.com/PMassicotte/nvim/blob/main/lua/nvim-quarto-config/init.lua

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Phil